# UITableView trailing swipe short vs long or return cell after long swipe

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, ios11

In my table view I implement the `func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, trailingSwipeActionsConfigurationForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UISwipeActionsConfiguration?` to provide deleting functionality. I want to confirm the deletion so I show an `UIAlertController` with a Delete or Cancel prompt. When the user decides to cancel, the cell is supposed to revert back to not editing. Normally this works by calling `tableView?.setEditing(false, animated: true)`, however this does not work for a long swipe.

Ideally I would like to have `tableView?.setEditing(false, animated: true)` work even when the cell has been fully swiped.

Other option is to simply omit the confirmation for a full swipe, but then I need a way to figure out whether was a swipe long or short.

What's the way how to achieve either of these outcomes?

Thanks

Comment: Turns out I might be wrong, now setEditing(false animated: true) doesn't do anything even for a short swipe. The problem therefore probably lies elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

I was dealing with the same issue right now. I tried everything but the resolution was simple. When you are creating UIContextualAction it takes handler as one parameter. The handler is somewhat like closure. The closure has 3 arguments. The last one is completion handler. Simply when you are done just call this handler with true and you are all set. I hope it helped.

```
let removeHandler:UIContextualActionHandler = { (action, view, finished) in
        let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Warning", message: "Do you really want to remove this?", preferredStyle: .alert)

        let removeButton = UIAlertAction(title: "Remove", style: .destructive, handler: { (action) in
            finished(true)
            CameraManager.shared.removeCamera(index: indexPath.row)
            tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .automatic)
        })

        let cancelButton = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .cancel, handler: nil)

        alert.addAction(removeButton)
        alert.addAction(cancelButton)
        self.present(alert, animated: true)
    }
    let removeAction = UIContextualAction(style: .destructive, title: "Odstrániť", handler: removeHandler)

    let conf = UISwipeActionsConfiguration(actions: [removeAction])
```